# Why two variables for accepting incoming connections?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have coded a simple **client** and **server** in python, I have no problem to understand and run the **client** however I have an issue understanding and running the **server**.

This is my code for the **client** which works fine:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 12345

sock.connect((host, port))
data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()
print("Message: ", data)
print("Finished successfully")
```

And here is my **server**, now here you will notice that the *sock.accept()* has two variables in front *connection* & *addr* and that is what I am trying to understand? Why do I need to have these two variables? Why can't I have one? Why do I need to have two variables that are assigned with the same functionality? When I run this code it works fine:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 12345

sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
    print("Waiting for a connection...")
    connection, addr = sock.accept()
    #print("Incomming connection from", addr)
    msg = b'This is a test.'
    connection.send(msg)
    connection.close()
    break
print("Finished successfully")
```

However if I remove one variable, let's say *addr*:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 12345

sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
    print("Waiting for a connection...")
    connection = sock.accept()
    #print("Incomming connection from", addr)
    msg = b'This is a test.'
    connection.send(msg)
    connection.close()
    break
print("Finished successfully")
```

And I run this code, I get an error? Why would I get this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 16, in <module>
    connection.send(msg)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I just don't understand the logic behind this? These two variables are assigned with the same functionality and I don't see why I should have two same variables that have the ability to do the same thing?

Comment: asign 2 variables is just the pythonic way to unpack a 2 elements tuple

Comment: I wasn't really aware of that, I'm still learning python and apparently I haven't yet grasped all the concepts :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because as per documentation:

```
socket.accept()
```

*Accept a connection. The socket must be bound to an address and listening for connections. The return value is a pair (conn, address) where conn is a new socket object usable to send and receive data on the connection, and address is the address bound to the socket on the other end of the connection.*

It means you need to unpack the value whenever you use `socket.accept()` otherwise you receive a tuple object, so

```
conn, address = socket.accept() # correct way
conn = socket.accept() # incorrect since conn here is a tuple
```

Comment: `conn = socket.accept()` still correct but you have to unpack later

Comment: yes it is still correct but he use it directly without unpacking